# Filtering scandir for filenames in folder C Language

Tags: c, scandir

I am using scandir() function in C, on a folder where i need to get files whose filenames are exactly = "exe".

How can i filter the entries returned by scandir?

Third argument of scandir is filter:

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
       int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
       int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

could it be useful for my purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the filter argument is a function pointer that lets you pass in a function to filter the results. You might want to write a function like the one below and pass it by name as the value for filter.

```
int file_select(const struct dirent *entry)
{
   return strcmp(entry->d_name, "exe");
}
```

Comment: Your return is not right! It should be `return (0 == strcmp(entry->d_name, "exe");`